# Как изменить ссылку в попапе региональности? Сайт на Битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть сайт: https://e-gifts24.ru/
Он создан с помощью CMS Битрикс.
Когда мы заходим на сайт, предлагается выбрать Страну (Беларусь, Россия).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я хочу поменять ссылку (вставить другой url).
В частности (Беларусь (цены в BYN)).
Но проблема в том, что когда я захожу в исходный код, я не вижу где менять эту ссылку... Там вообще нет никаких ссылок.

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, что нужно изменить, чтобы менять ссылки?

```
<div class="popup_regions_custom">
<div class="items only_city">
    <?if($arResult['REGIONS']):?>
        <div class="block cities">
            <div class="items_block scrollblock">
                <?foreach($arResult['REGIONS'] as $key => $arItem):?>
                    <?$bCurrent = ($arResult['CURRENT_REGION']['ID'] == $arItem['ID']);?>
                    <div class="item <?=($bCurrent ? 'current' : '');?>">
                        <?if($bCurrent):?>
                            <a href="<?=$arItem['URL'];?>" data-id="<?=$arItem['ID'];?>" class="name city_link"><?=$arItem['NAME'];?></a>
                        <?else:?>
                            <a href="<?=$arItem['URL'];?>" data-id="<?=$arItem['ID'];?>" class="name city_link"><?=$arItem['NAME'];?></a>
                        <?endif;?>
                    </div>
                <?endforeach;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?endif;?>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.popup_regions_custom a').on('click', function(e){
            var _this = $(this);
            $.removeCookie('current_region');
            $.cookie('current_region', _this.data('id'), {path: '/',domain: arMaxOptions['SITE_ADDRESS']});
            $('.confirm_region').remove();
            //if(typeof _this.data('href') !== 'undefined')
            //    location.href = _this.data('href');
        });

        $('.form_head').html('<h2>Выберите Вашу страну:</h2>');
        $('.popup_regions_custom a[data-id$="340"]').html('Россия (цены в RUR)');
        $('.popup_regions_custom a[data-id$="338"]').html('Беларусь (цены в BYN)');
    });
</script>
```

Спасибо.

Comment: `href="<?=$arItem['URL'];?>"` вот тут ссылка, в поле URL элемента инфоблока, видимо.

Comment: @u_mulder, "мы пролетаем над офисом 1с..." (с) анекдот.... вы не 1с программист?

Comment: @u_mulder вставлял я туда нужный мне URL. Ссылка меняется, но исчезает текст Беларусь (цены в BYN). + Заголовок (Выберите Вашу страну:) заменяется на Выберете ваш город.